# What's the difference between ASP.NET Core Hosted and Server-Side Blazor, really?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm still struggling to understand the difference between *ASP.NET Core Hosted* and *Server-side* Blazor. I know same question already [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332097/blazor-asp-net-core-hosted-vs-server-side-in-asp-net-core), but it's not satisfying. In fact, I couldn't find the satisfying answer anywhere - the answers were more or less the same.

If *hosted* option uses server (IIS, Kestrel), then why *server-side*? Confusing... It's a shame that official documentation didn't shed the light either...

## UPDATE

The confusion stems from the fact that we have THREE options to create Blazor application. After executing `dotnew new --list` I get:

1. `dotnet new blazorserver` (Blazor Server App)
2. `dotnet blazorwasm` (Blazor WebAssembly App)

However, there's a third option:

3. `dotnet blazorwasm --hosted` (or `dotnet blazor --hosted`)

It's the same as check box in Visual Studio when creating application:

[image: IMG1]

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models) says:

> you have the option of configuring the app to use an ASP.NET Core
> backend by selecting the ASP.NET Core hosted check box

But no explanation was provided what does it mean...

Comment: Run on WebAssembly or the server
Blazor can run your client-side C# code directly in the browser, using WebAssembly. Because it's real .NET running on WebAssembly, you can re-use code and libraries from server-side parts of your application.

Alternatively, Blazor can run your client logic on the server. Client UI events are sent back to the server using SignalR - a real-time messaging framework. Once execution completes, the required UI changes are sent to the client and merged into the DOM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blazor, ASP.NET Core Hosted vs Server Side in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332097/blazor-asp-net-core-hosted-vs-server-side-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @samjudson If you paid attention, I have pointed to that question, but there's really no answer - that's why I'm asking again.

Comment: @JohnB The question is: if both options use server, why two options? 

Comment: look at it from the perspective of `where` the html gets created if that helps?

Comment: but i agree - the naming is bloody confusing and just when you get used to something, they go and change it!  :-)

Comment: Sometimes I think, Is 'Blazor' a 'old wine in a new bottle'? Because it looks like 
 related to SilverLight, the technology that is failed to appeal the mass market due to HTML5/CSS3 and JS based frameworks.

Comment: @Thangadurai - it's not a plugin so not the same as SL

Comment: @JohnB You're right))) But actually we have three options: blazorwasm, blazor hosted and blazor server-side! That is really confusing! :)

Comment: Related : [Understanding Blazor Assembly with ASP.net Core Hosted Model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62202022/60761)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update**

I see where you are coming from now. The confusion stems from the fact that you have an option called `--hosted` when using the client-hosted Blazor. This options means having Blazor to include ASP.NET Core runtime.

Why this option? Because you can write an offline app (e.g. calculator app) that does not need any kind of connection to external services, making ASP.NET Core irrelevant. However, you might want to write an online app that accesses online DB, external APIs, do verification, etc. For these kind of apps, you will need an ASP.NET Core stack to support your app.

Check this FAQ: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/wiki/FAQ#q-can-i-use-blazor-with-aspnet-core-on-the-server

**Original answer**

They are two hosting models: server-hosted, and client-hosted.

The difference is whether the app is hosted in server, or in client. Server hosting means your app logic runs in the server (you can think of it similar to what Web Forms is), you click on a button, an "Ajax" call sends the request, the server receives the request, and sends back the updated page. However, here it uses SignalR not Ajax, which is a low level socket communication (read efficient). And instead of updating a whole page, it updates only the relevant parts (thus it is a single page application).

On the other hand, client hosting means your logic runs within the browser. Think of it as if your C# logic is converted into JS, and it is embedded in the page. So the logic runs in the browser. This is possible after the introduction of WebAssembly which you might want to read about.

Let's say you want to create a calculator app. Your server hosted app will then need to communicate with the server to calculate and get the result for each calculation, while the client hosted does not need, and calculates the result in browser.

You might wonder, why we have two options. The reason being that support for WebAssembly (which a client hosted app relies on) is either incomplete or non-existant in many browsers, and performance differs widely too.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=wasm

Comment: So: 1) *blazor*: all the html rendering and app's logic are executed solely in browser; 2) *hosted*: browser is rendering only HTML, but all the logic is executed on the server (and interaction goes thru SignalR); 3) *server-side*: **???**

Comment: @JohnyL There are only two versions: client-hosted (code runs in browser) or server-hosted (code runs in server).

Comment: I have updated the question and showed those three options.

Comment: @JohnyL I get what you mean now. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying update! Now the puzzle has been solved! Thanks!

Comment: Downvoted because the first part of the answer isn't relevant to the question, and the second part doesn't properly explain the difference in how the Blazor app is served to the browser when the `--hosted` option is used.

Answer (score 128):

Re this part of your question:

> However, there's a third option:
>
> 3. `dotnet blazorwasm --hosted` (or `dotnet blazor --hosted`)
>
> It's the same as check box in Visual Studio when creating application:
>
> [image: IMG1]
>
> The
> [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models)
> says:
>
> > you have the option of configuring the app to use an ASP.NET Core
> > backend by selecting the ASP.NET Core hosted check box
>
> But no explanation was provided what does it mean...

## TL;DR

'Hosted' is used where you want the back-end of your site and the Blazor client using that back-end to both be hosted on the same website.

## In Detail

I agree, the documentation really isn't terribly clear about all of this, but the explanation is actually simpler than it seems:

### The Blazor app has to be 'hosted' somewhere

The first thing to remember is that the Blazor WebAssembly 'app' **is not a standalone website**, it's an app that's embedded in a website.  In a lot of cases it will behave like a website, because it will be used as a Single Page Application, but that is by no means required.

Essentially the Blazor WebAssembly app is a series of files and a JavaScript file that are created by compiling/publishing your Blazor project.

Those files then need to be put on a website somewhere and the combination of the name of a div tag and the Blazor JS file produced for your site deals with wiring your app files into the WebAssembly part of the browser so that it's then rendered on the page.

The key here is that the website 'hosting' your Blazor app **does not have to be an ASP.NET Core site**.  [It could be any site, pure HTML, Drupal, whatever,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57274230/1879019) it just needs to be shown on a browser that handles WebAssembly and JavaScript correctly.

### However, if you're also writing the backend of your site in ASP.NET Core, you can reuse that site

So, your Blazor project doesn't have to be hosted in a website written in ASP.NET Core, but it does have to be hosted somewhere (so the user can see it).

If you're also writing the back-end of the site at the same time, e.g. if you're writing an API or SignalR hub to send and receive data from your Blazor client, and if you're writing that back-end in ASP.NET Core, then you can reuse that same site to also host your Blazor client.

This scenario is **what the 'Hosted' option is for.**

If you create a project using the template in the screenshot above, with the 'hosted' option ticked, you'll see that the [YourProjectName].Server project that's created is the Start Up project, but the index.html page that's shown when you run that project has come from the [YourProjectName].Client project.

This approach means you only have one site running on your server (which could be good or bad) and also means you won't run across [any CORS issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors).

### But you don't have to have an ASP.NET Core site at all

If your Blazor site is a standalone site that doesn't read/write from any server, or if it only talks to 3rd party APIs or an existing Web API running on the older .NET Framework, then you don't actually need an ASP.NET Core site at all.

In **that case you don't use the 'hosted' option**.

Instead, you can simply publish your Blazor project and then take the files from the release folder and host them in any site.

Comment: Best answer of the lot. Do you know why the .Server project includes cshtml files and other bits that seem like they are pages? I thought cshtml files was the old name of razor pages? Why not calling them .razor? And how come they are still included on the server side? It seems to me the server side should have no pages and just API methods?

Comment: @BlazingNoob the cshtml pages actually **are** Razor pages, not Blazor components. If you look at the Startup.cs 'Configure' method you'll see the server app is configured to use both Razor pages and Blazor.  Blazor and Razor are sharing the routing for the site, and so when you navigate to root of the site you'll end up on a Blazor page.  However, if something causes an error before you get there you'll get taken to Error.cshtml (which is the 'outer' 'container' **'Host'** site's error page).  The _Layout.chstml page is the shared layout page that's just being used by the Error page.

Comment: I'm slowly getting a sense of things. Note that I've never done MVC. From what I understand, historically in MVC apps, .cshtml is the extension for pages written in the Razor syntax (blend of html and C#). When Blazor was launched, they kept this for pages, but introduced .razor for components only. Then decided all pages and components should be suffixed with .razor. But when creating a hosted Blazor Webassembly project, the server part is actually an MVC web app, which has retained the cshtml suffix for its only page: the error page. Did I get this right? Most confusing for me at first.

Comment: @BlazingNoob, that's exactly right.  Just to confuse things further, on the MVC side there are actually two types of server-served pages that use the .cshtml suffix:  MVC pages and Razor Pages.  Razor Pages are a lighter weight version of an MVC page that don't require a standalone controller to serve them.  That's why there's no controller endpoint serving up the Error page.  

That then got very confusing when they decided to call Blazor components 'Razor Components' rather than 'Blazor components'.  I'm still hoping they will change their mind on that.

Comment: @tomRedox Thanks so much for your answer! I have one more clarification to ask about since it is not clearly mentioned anywhere in Microsoft's docs. Does the Blazor WASM hosted backend ("Project.Server") actually use a Blazor Server (Uses SignalR by default) or a typical .NET Core Web API project? I'm guessing the latter because I don't see any Blazor Server middleware or websocket connections being established on the frontend, but this isn't explicitly (Or clearly implicitly) stated in the docs. Thanks again for taking the time to write your original answer.

Comment: @clarkbrent it's a Web API project.  There's a separate command for adding Blazor server side to am MVC site

Comment: @tomRedox I had a feeling. I think what really muddied up my understanding is that the Blazor WASM hosted backend project is named identical to what a typical Blazor Server project would be instead of a typical Web API project name. Thanks again!

Comment: @tomRedox, this should be accepted answer. Thanks for the explanation, now it's clear for me.

Comment: @tomRedox thanks first of all for the clear explanation! I understood that in the WASM hosted backend we create both a Client and a Server. The 2 of these do not communicate with SignalR but normal HTTP calls since the backend is a simple .NET Core Web Api. Question: did I understand well that in this scenario, even though we have a backend, the computation still happens on the frontend side like in the simple WASM scenario (non dotnet core hosted)? Thank you!

Comment: @Tarta in Blazor WebAssembly the whole Blazor app is a self-contained entity that runs solely on the client.  It may use a REST API, GraphQL, SignalR etc. to talk to some other service, but that's not required.  When you use the Hosted option the server is simply providing a website to host the Blazor WebAssembly app, there's no code related to the actual operation of the Blazor app on the server.  You could then have a REST API (or whatever) on that Server site too, but you'd only do that if your Blazor app needed data from the server.

Comment: @tomRedox clear! thank you! I wanted to double check because we are talking about client and server here. If our Blazor App was still relying on the server for all the computation then it would be exactly the same as the Blazor Server model. Instead, as you just confirmed, it's a full WASM entity, plus there is a backend in case needed. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tarta re this bit "If our Blazor App was still relying on the server for all the computation then it would be exactly the same as the Blazor Server model".  That's not quite right, in Blazor Server the code runs on the server, so you don't need a rest API, you can talk straight to EF for example (which won't work in Blazor WASM). Blazor Server is more like a WinForms app in that regard.  Blazor Server is effectively behaving like a TS/RDP session where user inputs are passed to the server, then all the work is done on the server and then the changes to the UI are passed back to the client

Comment: @tomRedox thanks again for the explanation! If I may ask you another question.. this sentence set me off: "or if it only talks to 3rd party APIs", related to the fact that if our WASM app just needs to talk to 3rd party APIs then we don't need to make it being hosted by .net core. The thing is that WASM doesn't make any HTTP calls by itself, the browser does. And all browsers are built to refuse to connect to any endpoint not specified through a CORS policy. Does your sentence still stand? Not an accusation of any kind of course :) I just need to understand haha

Comment: @Tarta I haven't had the fun of CORS with Blazor yet, so honestly I don't know.  All our stuff to date has been calling our own APIs.  I assume there must be a way to do that, it's a pretty standard use case.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it's the only answer as of today that actually addresses the question.

Comment: How is the Server App configured to start the Client App? There doesn't seem to be a link between the two except for the project reference.

Comment: @JensMander if you're talking about Blazor WebAssembly then it isn't; the Client App is standalone and will 'run' once the page it's hosted on is rendered.  The client app may then make REST or other calls back to a server app, other web-service or nothing at all.  Don't forget there doesn't need to be a Server App at all, the Blazor WebAssembly could exist entirely on it's own and be hosted on a static html page.  Hopefully I understood the question correctly, but if not I'd suggest re-reading the documentation for Blazor and asking a separate new question if anything's still unclear.

Comment: If you create a Blazor App with the "hosted" option checked, it will create three projects Server, Client and Shared. The server project has a project dependency on the client project. If you start the server project, it will open a browser with the client app. My question was how the server App knows how to start the Client App? Where is the Link between the two / how is the project reference enough for the server to know the client and to start it? There is no command in the server program code that takes care of that. It happens seemingly "automatically". Whats the automatism?

Comment: @JensMander it's a good question, one I don't know the answer to!  Ask a new question, one of the usual suspects will definitely know!   Stick a link to the question back here too if you get a chance, I'd be interested to know too!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I think this is well-answered

Comment: Couple questions: Q1. Is server in the Hosted model equivalent to a .NET Core API (that doesn't do SignalR connections to the Blazor WASM client)? Q2. Does it provide any benefits to let's say having a .NET Core API running in the Server (hosted through for eg: Azure App Service) with a Blazor WASM running in the client (hosted through for eg: Static Websites)? Please elaborate on these questions in your answer if possible.

Answer (score 18):

The question is about the option "ASP.NET Core hosted" in Visual Studio, while creating a new Blazor Project with Blazor WebAssembly App.

Selecting this option scaffolds out 3 Projects for you (vs 1 WebAssembly project, if this option is not selected)

1. Server Side Blazor Project
2. Client Side Blazor Project (WebAssembly)
3. Shared project for shared entities between Server and Client Projects.

With this option you can have

1. Blazor WebAssembly only option for sections of your project where the logic can execute in browser.
2. Server hosted option where all the processing is done on server and only HTML is rendered onto the browser.

When deployed, all these projects go to the same location. So if you have a requirement for both Server Side as well as Client side options, then go for it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for one more good answer! +1 for effort! 

Answer (score 10):

I too had the same confusion while reading the documentation. But it was explained in [Blazor webassembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1) section

dotnet blazorwasm - [is a standalone project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1#standalone-deployment)

dotnet blazorwasm --hosted (or dotnet blazor --hosted) - [is a projected hosted with ASP.NET Core backing API's.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1#hosted-deployment-with-aspnet-core)

> A hosted deployment serves the Blazor WebAssembly app to browsers from an ASP.NET Core app that runs on a web server.
>
> The client Blazor WebAssembly app is published into the /bin/Release/{TARGET FRAMEWORK}/publish/wwwroot folder of the server app, along with any other static web assets of the server app. The two apps are deployed together. A web server that is capable of hosting an ASP.NET Core app is required. For a hosted deployment, Visual Studio includes the Blazor WebAssembly App project template (blazorwasm template when using the dotnet new command) with the Hosted option selected (-ho|--hosted when using the dotnet new command).

Answer (score 9):

Here are my two cents.

Create a Blazor WebAssembly App with ASP.NET Core Hosted check box selected.

[image: Blazor Web Assembly app with Asp.net core hosted]

Once created observe the project references.

[image: Blazor WebAssembly App with Asp.Net Core Hosted selected project structure]

Note that the server project references client project.
I had this same confusion as others, that the client calls the server, and that they are two independent Visual Studio projects. So this project references puzzled me.

**The fact is client project is hosted by and served by the server project. When we want to run the app, we need to run the server project and not the client project.**

So when you want to run the Solution(App), you must ensure to set the **Server** project as the startup project and not both the server and client. Due to my initial misunderstanding, I was setting multiple startup project, thinking that the client(something like React App) calls the server(WebApi), and that they both should be running simultaneously, for the client to call the server.

[image: The server project set as startup project]

The above is correct, but the following is **INCORRECT**.

[image: Setting both client and server as startup projects.]

If you do that, you get the following error, and this stung me.

Microsoft Visual Studio - One or more errors occurred. Failed to launch debug adapter error

[image: Failed to launch debug adapter error from Visual Studio]

And finally if you are thinking to dockarize by adding docker files and docker-compose files for different kinds of Blazor apps, do take a look at this [github repo](https://github.com/jongio/BlazorDocker).

Specifically for this kind of apps that we are talking about take a look at [this](https://github.com/jongio/BlazorDocker#hosted) and [this folder](https://github.com/jongio/BlazorDocker/tree/master/Hosted) in that repo.

Comment: Is it possible to route to pages in the server?

Comment: It's a good answer. Where in startup file is a definition for starting a client? I mean, it need to be configured somewhere, which client should start.

Comment: Couple questions: Q1. Is server in the Hosted model equivalent to a .NET Core API (that doesn't do SignalR connections to the Blazor WASM client)? Q2. Does it provide any benefits to let's say having a .NET Core API running in the Server (hosted through for eg: Azure App Service) with a Blazor WASM running in the client (hosted through for eg: Static Websites)? Please elaborate on these questions in your answer if possible.

Answer (score 6):

**Blazor-WASM**

The application can work offline after the first loading. As an Example If you make Loan calculator with Blazor WASM, you can send all the data, business logic and validation to the client side in the first load like loan types, loan rates, max repayment period like that then because of the logic also in client side, it don't need do the communication with the server again and again when you change the loan type or repayment period because business logic in client side using the user selected data Blazor can render the UI and show the result.

**Blazor-server**

Application use server to render the UI so as on the Loan application if user change the loan type blazor send that user change value to server using SignalR and in the server has data and the logic for get the result, after that server render UI and send UI changes to the client side using SignalR and redraw the UI in clients screen.

**Blazor-ASP.NET Core Hosted**

Visual studio generate 3 projects in the core hosted template

- ClientProject - this is a Blazor-WASM application
- ServerProject - this is a .NET CORE API
- SharedClassProject - this is a class library that holds shared
  objects between client and server

As the loan example in the first load loan types and calculation logic are loaded in client side.

If the user selects the loan type Blazor creates an http call to the API application to get the loan rates according to the selected loan type if the interest rate is in the db.

Then the user enters the repayment period because of calculation logic in the client side. Now the application can calculate the result and render the UI to show the result. So with this model you can keep some data or logic in the server and other data or logic on the client side.

Comment: Server project is Web API - haha wish they'd have called it that I thought it was a Blazor Server app!