# Blazor WASM - How to debug the Program.cs (VS2022 or JB Rider)?

Tags: c#, debugging, blazor, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I have been struggling for a while using Blazor WASM on .Net Core 6.0 (Stand-alone and Hosted) to debug my `program.cs` file without success.

As Microsoft mentioned, we can debug the app using the Chromium option to debug the app on the Browser (Google or Edge)... but still the debug is clunky and doesn't work as expected.

Is there any other alternative to debug my C# code on Visual Studio 2022 or JetBrains Ryder IDEs?

#### References

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

[Understanding Blazor Assembly with ASP.net Core Hosted Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202022/understanding-blazor-assembly-with-asp-net-core-hosted-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to debug Blazor C# code (Even the `program.cs` file) without too much effort... so far it works pretty well for me.

The workaround works for VS 2022 or JetBrains Rider...

#### Steps

1. Open your IDE
2. Open the Terminal console CTRL+`
3. Use the dotnet CLI to watch your project: `dotnet.exe watch --project ./PROJECT_PATH/PROJECT.csproj`
   [image: CLI]
4. Then, go to `Attach to process` option in your IDE and attach the process that is currently running...

   - **Visual Studio 2022**: Menu > Debug > Attach to Process
     [image: VS2022 config]
   - **JetBrains Rider**: Menu > Run > Attach to Process
     [image: Rider Config]
5. Then you should be able to debug, put breakpoints, watch your variables and whatever you need from there...

...now, with that you don't will be able to put a breakpoint in your `Program.cs`... because while you are doing the previous steps, the app will be up and running...

Then... just include the following lines at the beginning of the `Program.cs` file.

```
Console.WriteLine("Attach your process into your IDE...");

// Wait 20 seconds to the developer attach the process for debugging
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

Console.WriteLine("Start Program.cs");
```

This will give you enough time to run the application and attach the process to your IDE... and from there you should be able to debug your program and check configs, Dependency Injection and services stuff.

So, at the end you just add some buffer time that gives you enough time to attach the process to your IDE and be able to be debugged.

#### Results

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with Visual Studio 2022, Windows 11, Blazor WASM and .netCore 7 and Kestrel whith this procedure:

In server project in launchSettings.json i make this settings

```
"Kestrel": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchUrl": "http://localhost:29701",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://*:29701;https://*:29702"
  },
  "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",      
  "applicationUrl": "http://*:29701;https://*:29702"
},
```

The secret and important is you have in your Client Project the same configuration name "Kestrel" and diferent port

```
"Kestrel": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchUrl": "http://localhost:29701",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://*:7297;http://*:5035"
  },
  "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
  "applicationUrl": "https://*:7297;http://*:5035"
},
```

Another settings are:

Debug Symbols -> PDB file, portable Across Platform

Script Debuging disable

Web Browser Edge , Works with chrome too.

Optimize Code for Debug  = False

In my machine this is solved the problem, I got the same results in a diferent machine