# What's the purpose of "ASP.NET Core hosted" in Blazor WASM app?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

When creating a new Blazor WebAssembly App in Visual Studio 2022 there's a "ASP.NET Core hosted" option (with a useless tool tip).

[image]

If you tick this instead of 1 WASM project in the solution, there are 3, Client (WASM), Shared and Server.

The Blazor Server app has no pages though it is the startup project. When you run it it calls the WASM Blazor Client app.

I can't find an explanation of what the purpose of doing this is? If I deploy a WASM app to an IIS server it runs fine without a Server app.

Note, I'm not asking the difference between Blazor Server (server side code running on the server that sends HTML to the client) and Blazor Client WASM (C# code compiled into WebAssembly that runs in the browser). I know this.

I'm asking why you'd want a Blazor Server app in a Solution with a Blazor WASM app if you intend to create a WASM app.

I can't find a direct answer to this. Either this article doesn't answer it - or I'm missing something:
[What's the difference between ASP.NET Core Hosted and Server-Side Blazor, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093386/whats-the-difference-between-asp-net-core-hosted-and-server-side-blazor-really)

I can't find anything else.

So what is the purpose of the Blazor Server app, and why is it running first then calling the WASM app. Also how would you host that?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I'm aware that a WASM app is client side only, and you need, say, a Web API project to connect to in order to pull data from a web server.

Is this '.net Core Hosted' template doing something I couldn't do myself by creating a solution with a WASM project - then adding a Web API project (and various shared projects)?

Comment: Having a server can simplify the provision API's Controller's and Hubs.

Comment: _"The Blazor Server app has no pages"_ : it will when you use MS Identity for signing in. That uses razor pages.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Blazor server app almost works like a distributed desktop app. Every event on the browser is sent to the server, the server handles the event, calculates resulting changes in the DOM and sends the diffed DOM which is then applied to the page by the browser side js and the page is updated.

The use of traditional web API style pattern is completely optional here. In a Blazor server app you need not write a single web API for the app to work. Everything can be written as if it is a single desktop application.

A webassembly app is richer. The app actually runs on the browser, everything (event handling, UI refresh etc) is done on the client side only.  These are so called 'static apps/websites' which, once loaded, require nothing else to execute. Imagine a single player, flash style games - they don't need connection to a database/application server.

However, there are hardly any rich apps which do not require even the basic database connectivity. So how does an app - say a gaming app that maintains a leaderboard - communicate with application servers and databases which maintain application data remotely?
This is where the hosted model comes handy. In a typical web application scenario, you essentially need three components 1) Client side code - the app 2) Server side code - the web API - to maintain state 3) Shared object model - so that the first two can communicate seamlessly.
That is what you see in a ".net core hosted" option. The template creates boilerplate for all three components. The classes that will be used by both client and server are put in the shared project. The server side and client side logic exists in their respective projects and both of these refer to the shared project **without** referring to each other.

Is it mandatory to have this to run a webassembly app? No. You can write your server side logic on any platform of your choice - it need not be asp.net - and call that API from the Blazor webassembly app . However, you will still end up creating mappers for client server communication classes. The .net core hosted option offers a very convenient way to do this.

Comment: Thanks. That's a useful template. Would I still have to use WebAPI (JSON etc), JWT etc - to get data that's on the server to display in the app, login etc? Or does this template provide some other way of doing that?

Comment: Is the template fundamentally any different to me just making a solution with a Blazor WASM project, then adding a Web API project, models project etc?

Comment: Because both client and server share the same object model, JSON serialization is simply a matter of POSTing and reading responses using the out of the box .net core library JSON classes. You don't need additional mapping. By JWT, I assume you are talking about auth. You can choose to go with bundled auth patterns by selecting one from the dropdown ("Authentication type"). If you want to set up some other authentication, then you have to write your own code.

Comment: This says '.net Core hosting' uses SignalR for something: https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/3-blazor-hosting-models.aspx
So it's doing more than just creating a Web API for you?!

Comment: Deleted my comment. See the point of hosted model is to allow client server decoupling and letting the developer choose a way for client server communication - WebAPI, gRPC, SignalR or any other. So this may include signalr. Don't want the readers to be under the impression that SignalR is exclusively for Blazor server or anything. For example, in a multi player gaming or chatting app, you will want to use SignalR hub for communication.

Answer (score 1):

> If I deploy a WASM app to an IIS server it runs fine without a Server app.

Yes it does. But being a Client app it cannot access any server resources (like a Database or the Filesystem). It is also restricted by CORS to access only certain webresources.

So a Client app usually has to to rely on an API server to get anything done. And that is what the Hosted template provides.

Note that the Shared project contains C# classes and code that both the Client and Server can use, that gives you strongly typed DTOs with a single point of definition.

The main reason for and benefit of this template are these 2 lines in Server\Program.cs

```
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
...
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

This makes the Server host the Client. While still being a fully capable API server.

Comment: Sure. But is this template doing something I couldn't do myself by creating a solution with a WASM project - then adding a Web API project (and various shared projects)?

Comment: Also why a Blazor Server app - not a Web API app? Wouldn't Web API be better for this? What does Blazor Server give you here that Web API (say) doesn't?

Comment: The Blazor Server project _is_ a Web API app. The template is just for convenience, the Server also hosts the Client on the same URL. That makes CORS a non-issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you mean by that please?

Comment: Also, how does deployment work? Thx

Comment: Why doesn't the template create a Web API rather than Blazor Server project? Seems like Blazor Server is intended for something entirely different (building HTMl on the server using Blazor then sending that to the client - as well as DOM updates to the client over SignalR) - rather than providing an API? Is there some other value it can add??

Comment: Look again. There is no Blazor-Serverside project here. The server project in this template ___is___ an asp.net WebAPI project.

Comment: AHH! Makes sense. The fact it was called 'myproj.Server' - made me think it was Blazor Server. So that's just a Web API project? (hard to tell now they all seem to just be Console Apps in properties). Only the Server project is set to run - so how does that open the client project? (sorry for all questions). For deployment I just deploy the two apps on the server - how do I point client at server?

Comment: Yes, this is getting too long. Blazor-serverside is also just a WebAPI server with a SignalR package and some specifc middleware. Make sure you go through the FetchData page sample from beginning to end.

Comment: Thanks - what does it use SignalR for exactly? Seems like it's doing something standard Web API wouldn't do?